# Cost associated set problem NP-hard

Tags: computational-complexity, combinatorial-optimization, np

I have the following problem. I wonder whether or not it appears in the literature. Is it NP-hard?

> Given a set $S = \{1,2,\ldots,m\}$, and $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ are subsets of $S$. Each set $A_i$ has an associated weight $x_i\geq 0$ (unknown). Given $c_i,\ldots,c_n$ and $s_1, \ldots,s_m$. The question is how can we choose at most $k$ numbers from $S$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^nc_ix_i$ is maximum, provided that if $j\in S$ is chosen then we must have $\sum\limits_{i: j\in A_i}x_i \leq s_j$, otherwise if $j$ is not chosen, then $x_i = 0$ for all $A_i$ contains $j$. This problem can be formulated as the following MILP. Let $y_j = 1$ if $j$ is chosen and $y_j = 0$ otherwise, then we have the following model $\max \sum_ic_ix_i$ s.t $\sum\limits_{i: j\in A_i}x_i \leq s_jy_j$ for all $j\in S, \sum_jy_j \leq k,  x_i \geq 0, y_j \in \{0, 1\}$.

Thank you in advance!